# How to make a website for multiple events registration?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Suppose, I want to make a website for a college fest. I want to add Registration and Login feature in it. Also, there are many events. So, if someone logins and registers for an event; how should I keep a separate tab on how many users registered for that event?

This is the workflow that I expect:
1. User registers.
2. User gets user-id and logins to the website
3. From the list of various events, he selects one and registers.
4. He gets a mail confirming that he has successfully registered for the event.

How should I go on developing???

I have a table that contains following attributes:
Name
UserId
DOB
College

If a user registers for an event, how can I add in this table the event name?

Comment: You'd store the details in a database and query it for stats. That said, this question is far too broad to get a useful answer here. When you have a specific problem or bug (I wanted it to do `x` but it did `y`) then we might be able to help you. http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Tell us what have you done so far?

Comment: A page has been designed. We have created tables:
Name
UserId
DOB
College

If UserId 1 registers for an event abc, how can I add it in database that he has registered for an event--event name?

Answer (score 2):

The question you're asking is so broad that I could write a book to answer it. In fact, lots of people [have done so](http://www.php-intro.com/).

You need to learn about all of the following topics before you can hope to solve this problem...

- HTML
- Creating a simple page in PHP
- Creating a MySQL database to store your information
- Use PHP to connect to MySQL and store users/registrations & query for registrations
- Use PHP to send emails
- Set up a webserver to actually host your content
- Publish your site
- Set up a domain name to point at your web server

This is still an imcomplete list, but once you know how to do each of the above, the problem becomes fairly simple.

Unfortunately, nobody here is going to do all that for you. You need to start reading tutorials and examples online, get PHP and MySQL set up on your local machine and then start practicing.

If along the way you have a specific problem, Stack Overflow is a good place to ask - but your question has to be specific and detailed, preferably including code/SQL so others can see exactly what you've done without guessing

#### EDIT:

It seems like you're asking about the database design.

I'd expect you to have Three tables...

```
Users
    ID, Name, EmailAddress, etc...
    
Events
    ID, Name, Description, Location, Date, etc...

Registrations
    UserID, EventID
```

As users are created, they go in the users table. Events go in the events table and a user registration is recorded by putting an entry in the Registrations table, containing the ID of the appropriate user and event.

Comment: I am very much aware that I have to develop this in PHP. I have also created the login and registration page. The question has been edited, so can you please go through it again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand problem.

In database you should have a table 'many to many' type where you connect users with events.

From this table you get what events has a user, and which users are registered for event.

Comment: I am still confused about it. Can you please elaborate some more on this?

Comment: An answer can only be as in-depth as the question, technically he gave you want you asked for.